# Sed Bash script only runs first line of sed

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, sed, files

My `bash` script only runs first line of `sed`. The command i use to run it:

```
sed -f sedhw.bash thesbians.txt
```

Contents of `sedhw.bash`

```
s/[0-9]*//g
s/1908/---/g; s/1895/---/g; s/1903/---/g
s/,.*//g
s/^[^"]*"/"/
s/,[^",]*"/,/;s/"//g
```

I need it to run each command in the file once at a time giving me 5 different outputs not one output.

Text file looks like this

```
Chase,Cornelius 1943 "Chevy"
Davis,Ruth      1908 "Bette"
Keaton,Joseph   1895 "Buster"
Stone,Emily     1988 "Emma"
Lee,Shelton     1957 "Spike"
Reynolds,Mary   1932 "Debbie"
Crosby,Harry    1903 "Bing"
Fey,Stamatina   1970 "Tina"
```

Comment: I don't follow you. The `sed` script contains eight commands to be applied to the file `thesbians.txt`. The output from these commands is sent to _stdout_. If you want each line of your script to be treated as a separate invocation of `sed`, (a) what input should each take, (b) where should each output go? Please [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/644929/edit) to clarify.

Comment: Also, what is this "bash script" you mention? You have shown us a `sed` script, is there also a bash script involved somewhere? Where? How?

Comment: each line starting with s is one command so there are 5 commands total in my script.  when i run the script using sed -f on the thesbians txt file it only runs the first command and not the rest

Comment: @JimmyGonzalez All lines of the `sed` script is applied to each line of your text file. This is how `sed` operates. It would be interesting to see the contents of your text file and to know what edits you need to do to it.

Comment: @Kusalananda updated

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text.  Copy-paste the text instead, so we can use it to test our answers.

Comment: Related: [How do i use a sed command to get the following outputs of this file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/643870)

Comment: @markgraf updated

Comment: @Kusalananda yeah you removed my post so now i added a photo of the layout and text so you can test it. im still having trouble getting my outputs but i have the sed commands which need to be used. i just need to run a script to modify the text file using those commands and i need 5 outputs not one output of all the commands.

Comment: I did not remove your post. I closed it so that you could replace the images in it with text. I would then reopen it and anyone could have answered.

Comment: @Kusalananda ok thanks i will try the answer below and see if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@roaima](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/100397/roaima) and [@kusalananda](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/116858/kusalananda) commented already, your `sedhw.bash` is a sedfile.

`sed -f sedhw.bash thesbians.txt` will run all the sed-commands in sedhw.bash against the file thesbians.txt

What you want to do *instead* is to loop over the lines in sedhw.bash and execute each line to produce a new output-file:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read num line; do 
     sed "$line" thesbians.txt > output.${num}.txt
done < <(nl sedhw.bash)
```

To explain:
`nl sedhw.bash` will number your commands and "tab-separate" linenumber and command:

```
     1  s/[0-9]*//g
     2  s/1908/---/g; s/1895/---/g; s/1903/---/g
     3  s/,.*//g
     4  s/^[^"]*"/"/
     5  s/,[^",]*"/,/;s/"//g
```

`<(...)` will present the commands output as a file the while-loop.

The loop will be fed this "file" line by line by `<` and read the tab-separated fields into the variables "num" and "line".

`sed` executes the command "$line" and writes it to a file numbered with the corresponding line in sedhw.bash.

**Result**

```
$ for item in output*; do echo; echo "=== $item ==="; cat $item ; done 

=== output.1.txt ===
Chase,Cornelius "Chevy"
Davis,Ruth      "Bette"
Keaton,Joseph   "Buster"
Stone,Emily     "Emma"
Lee,Shelton     "Spike"
Reynolds,Mary   "Debbie"
Crosby,Harry    "Bing"
Fey,Stamatina   "Tina"

=== output.2.txt ===
Chase,Cornelius 1943 "Chevy"
Davis,Ruth      ---  "Bette"
Keaton,Joseph   ---  "Buster"
Stone,Emily     1988 "Emma"
Lee,Shelton     1957 "Spike"
Reynolds,Mary   1932 "Debbie"
Crosby,Harry    ---  "Bing"
Fey,Stamatina   1970 "Tina"

=== output.3.txt ===
Chase
Davis
Keaton
Stone
Lee
Reynolds
Crosby
Fey

=== output.4.txt ===
"Chevy"
"Bette"
"Buster"
"Emma"
"Spike"
"Debbie"
"Bing"
"Tina"

=== output.5.txt ===
Chase,Chevy
Davis,Bette
Keaton,Buster
Stone,Emma
Lee,Spike
Reynolds,Debbie
Crosby,Bing
Fey,Tina
```

Comment: tried implementing the while loop but im still having a syntax problem somewhere smh

Comment: Try it all in one line, in the same directory as thesbians.txt:  while read num line; do sed "$line" thesbians.txt > output.${num}.txt ; done < <(nl sedhw.bash)

Comment: ok ill try it then how should i run it how i have been using sed -f ?

Comment: Just copy-paste the line below.  No `-f`necessary.  `-f` applies sed-files.  You do not use one here.

Comment: while read num line; do sed "$line" thesbians.txt > output.${num}.txt ; done < <(nl sedhw.bash)